# Can't delete listview item on a first try

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

So here's my problem. I'm creating simple android app and I want to remove item from a List view. My code kind of works, the problem is that item is deleted after second click (remove button). Also i need to select item second time.

What I wanna do is to select an item one time, and delete it by clicking remove button.

Here is my code for Remove-button.

```
private void Remove_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
    {
        conn.CreateTable<Book>();

        var books = conn.Table<Book>().ToList();
        booksListView.ItemsSource = books;

        var selItem = (Book)booksListView.SelectedItem;

        Book remBook = new Book()
        {
            Id = selItem.Id,
            Name = selItem.Name,
            Author = selItem.Author
        };

        conn.Delete(remBook);
    };
}
```

I have also overrided OnAppearing(), can this be the problem?

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    Title = "Booklist";

    using (SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
    {
        conn.CreateTable<Book>();

        var books = conn.Table<Book>().ToList();

        booksListView.ItemsSource = books;
    }
}
```

I have done the adding part like this guy in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhWwBOoqXQ8

Comment: And now i just found solution. I added OnAppearing() after sqlite-part, and now it is working. Should i or can i delete this post somehow? Or is it necessary? This was my first post.

Comment: Hi, you post an answer, and accept it to close this case.

Comment: seems like you haven't updated your list item source after deleting record from db, you don't need `onAppearing()` to get this work